# What type of terminal is the ubuntu terminal in WSL?

Tags: gnome-terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu on Windows 10 through WSL and I'd like to install a theme in the terminal, but I don't know what kind of terminal it is. It just says "Ubuntu" in the top bar for the window. What should I be looking for a theme for? How can I identify this terminal?

Answer (score 0):

For my WSL I installed VcXsrv so I could run Ubuntu Desktop which uses `gnome-terminal`. For themes see:

- [Color Scheme for Gnome Terminal and Pantheon Terminal](https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh)
- [Atom's One Dark and One Light theme for GNOME Terminal](https://github.com/denysdovhan/one-gnome-terminal)
- [gnome-terminal-themes](https://github.com/topics/gnome-terminal-themes)
- [179 Color Schemes For Your Gtk-Based Linux Terminal (Gnome Terminal, Tilix, Xfce Terminal, More)](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/179-color-schemes-for-your-gtk-based.html)

That said WSL Ubuntu Desktop's default Gnome terminal works really well for me except I had to remap the color blue because it was unreadable:

- [How to change the dark blue in wsl to something brighter?](https://superuser.com/questions/1365258/how-to-change-the-dark-blue-in-wsl-to-something-brighter)

Other users have many suggestions on different terminals you can use in WSL here:

- [A better terminal experience for Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827952/a-better-terminal-experience-for-windows-subsystem-for-linuxwsl/827956#827956)